# How to rename a Git workspace folder via Eclipse

Tags: git, directory, rename

I have a workspace folder name that appears to be reserved on my mac.  I cannot view the workspace folder in Finder because I named the Eclipse project with .service in the name.  The folder is navigable in terminal (bash) but not in finder.  In finder the workspace folder appears as such:

[image]

I have renamed the project folder in eclipse, but git still uses the previous name.  Can someone tell me how or point me in the direction as to how to rename a git workspace folder via Eclipse?  If I do it directly through git, it breaks my history.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `git mv` in order to reflect renaming files in Git, see [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mv.html) for more details.

Comment: that works to rename the folder, but in Eclipse I get the following error - `Git Respository Refresh has encountered a problem: Errors occurred while refreshing resources with the local file system.`  How do I do it through git via Eclipse?  Basically doing as you suggest with break my project and history.  Any advice?

Comment: Seems more like some Eclipse issues to me. Worst case, you can just recreate the project.